# How could I go about doing real-time system audio processing?

Tags: audio, real-time, audio-processing

I've been trying to find sources online for real-time system audio processing, but cannot seem to find anything I'm looking for. I've checked out some Python libraries, like PyAudio and librosa, but I believe their use-cases are different from what I'm looking for. I made a quick test with PyAudio, and it seems that I can only process my audio input (my system's microphone).

My goal is to play Spotify, a YouTube video, or whatever from my computer and to process the audio-- I'd like to process system sounds in real-time.

Comment: See the library sounddevice, it has the basics. https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.5/
If your computer has a monitoring/loopback device, it can be used to connect to what your computer plays

Comment: Python is too slow and non-deterministic for real-time audio. Don't use Python.

Comment: Is your goal to analyze the audio, or to modify the audio and output the modified version in real-time? How long of a delay is acceptable?

Comment: @JonNordby I appreciate your response. Honestly, I just wanted to try something new to control the LED lights in my room. I figured it'd be sort of cool to make the lights flicker along with my music. In terms of delay, I don't really mind. Obviously, the sooner, the better, but I don't mind.

I have no objections to moving to a faster language, like C++ -- I just assumed that Python might have the libraries to accomplish this.

Comment: Then, latency of about 150ms  is fine, as long as it's consistent. After that you'll start noticing that lighting is out of sync with the sound. All you really need is an FFT (and there's a lot of libraries doing it).

Answer (score 0):

To make lights react to an audio stream from the computer, the following approach can be used.

Use a library like [sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.5/) to get an input stream of audio. Configure it to give say 256 samples at a time at 16000 Hz (16 ms).

For each new chunk of audio, compute. For example, perform the FFT transform using [scipy.fft.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fft.html) to get the frequency spectrum, and sum up the frequency bands of interest. This gives an energy measurement and one can for example control brightness of lights to be proportional to that.